# Manage keyless table / entity with EF core 6 / OData

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a keyless data type I want to store in a table and manage using an API controller. However, an error is thrown in GetEdmModel:

[image: Odata validation error]

```
[Keyless]
public class UserDocuments
{
    [StringLength(30)]
    public string UserID { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public Guid DocumentID { get; set; } = Guid.Empty;
    public int Version { get; set; } = -1;  
}

public static IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{    
    ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<UserDocuments>("UserDocuments");
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

I also tried this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserDocuments>()
        .HasNoKey()
        .ToTable("UserDocuments");
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

but it didn't work either; And as far as I have understood it this is equivalent to using the [Keyless] annotation for class UserDocuments.

So how do I need to implement this to get the functionality I want?

Comment: The error has nothing to do with EF Core, hence cannot be solved by EF Core model configuration. In fact the error is from OData entity model, hence you need to figure out how to do what you are asking for there (OData library).